# ruby how to find mkmf?

Tags: ruby

When I do:

```
ruby extconf.rb
```

I get:

```
extconf.rb:24:in 'require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
```

When I start up `irb` and execute all commands from `extconf.rb` line by line it works fine (including `require 'mkmf'`).

How do I tell `ruby` where to find `mkmf` when obviously `irb` can find it.
I compiled ruby from source (1.9.1) and it's intalled in "non standard location".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby binary is lacking some `$LOAD_PATH`, it might be even collision between system `irb` and your custom `ruby`.

In any case, you can compare output of `ruby -e 'p $:'` and running `p $:` in irb...

When you find the missing directory, you can add it on commandline like this:

```
$ ruby -I/path/to/missing/loadpath extconf.rb
```

Although I'd seriously recommend reinstalling ruby properly, as this most likely points to a deeper problem than just missing loadpath in this instance.

Btw, how about installing ruby via [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/)? It's painless and works flawlessly on most setups. Not to mention you can use multiple Ruby versions on the same machine without any collisions.